# Laravel Storage::download File not found at path

Tags: laravel, file, download, storage

I'm trying to download files (`rapports`) I've uploaded but I'm getting a `File not found at path` error although the path is defined and seems correct. I've already created the symbolic link with the `php artisan storage:link` command.

Here is how I'm storing the `rapports`

```
$rapport = new Rapport;
        $rapport->themeRapport = $request->input('themeRapport');
        $rapport->resume = $request->input('resume');
        $rapport->auteur = $request->input('auteur');
        $rapport->encadrant = $request->input('encadrant');
        $rapport->cycle = $request->input('cycle');
        $rapport->filiere = $request->input('filiere');

        $fichierRapport = $request->file('fichierRapport');
        $fichierRapportName = $request->input('themeRapport') .'.'. $fichierRapport->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $fichierRapport->storeAs('rapports', $fichierRapportName);

     $rapport->fichierRapport = $fichierRapportName;
     $rapport->save();
```

So here is the `rapports` table structure

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRapportsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('rapports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('themeRapport');
            $table->string('resume');
            $table->string('auteur');
            $table->string('encadrant');
            $table->string('cycle');
            $table->string('filiere');
            $table->string('fichierRapport'); // File name of the uploaded file
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('rapports');
    }
}
```

The uploaded files go then to `storage/app/public/rapports` newly created directory as I set the `public` disk as the default one.

`config/filesystems.php` file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

In order to download, I've tried this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rapport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class downloadRapport extends Controller
{

    public function download($id){
        $rapport = Rapport::findOrFail($id);
        $url = Storage::url($rapport->fichierRapport);
        return Storage::download($url, $rapport->fichierRapport);
    }
}
```

which is getting me this error : `File not found at path: http:/localhost/storage/filename`

I tried also this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rapport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class downloadRapport extends Controller
{

    public function download($id){
        $rapport = Rapport::findOrFail($id);
        $url = Storage::disk('public')->url($rapport->fichierRapport);
        return Storage::download($url, $rapport->fichierRapport);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the same error : `File not found at path: http:/localhost/storage/filename`

I then tried the following, as files are uploaded in a new created directory `rapports`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rapport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class downloadRapport extends Controller
{

    public function download($id){
        $rapport = Rapport::findOrFail($id);
        $url = Storage::disk('public')->url('rapports/'.$rapport->fichierRapport);
        return Storage::download($url, $rapport->fichierRapport);
    }
}
```

Error : `File not found at path: http:/localhost/storage/rapports/filename`.

To get the full path, as I found out [here](https://mauricius.dev/get-the-full-path-of-a-file-using-the-storage-facade-on-laravel/), I tried this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rapport;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class downloadRapport extends Controller
{

    public function download($id){
        $rapport = Rapport::findOrFail($id);
        $url = Storage::disk('public')->path('rapports/'.$rapport->fichierRapport);

        return Storage::download($url, $rapport->fichierRapport);
    }
}
```

error : `File not found at path: C:/xampp/htdocs/MonProjet/storage/app/public/rapports/filename`
This full path is although where the files are actually located

What can be wrong with the code..? Am I missing something there? It's the first time for me to manipulate files in Laravel, your help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the below command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Your files will shown in `root/public/storage/your_folder`
You can just write a href to that file.

```
<a href="{{asset('/storage/folder/'.$file)}}">File Name</a>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have already run the command `php artisan storage:link` before. For the `<a href="{{asset('/storage/folder/'.$file)}}">File Name</a>` I've just tried it but I'm getting a 404 error. Another thing please, does the asset do the download? I think it's just the url it's referring to

Comment: 404 error will show, only if the path is incorrect, in this case. And `href` won't actually download it, if it is a image, image will be opened in the browser window. Then you can download. If it's a pdf, pdf will open in browser.